# How to replicate page transitions like in iTunes Quick Tour

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, segue, transition

If you open your iTunes and in the Help menu select iTunes Quick Tour you will be presented with a guide on how to use the app. I want to create something that resembles the transitions this window has. I am trying to start this using Storyboards instead of programmatically. The dots at the bottom allow you to jump to a specific view as well as transition to the next view or previous view.

I am developing this guide in swift for an OS X application.

1) Would this be easier done using a Page Controller or a Tab View Controller or something entirely else?

2) I googled but couldn't find any guides that were close enough to help me get this done. Any guides for this would be appreciated.